# pip install MySQL-python on windows 10, Python 3.5?

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows

when I try to install  pip install MySQL-python on windows 10 I got :

```
C:\Users\ghina>pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ghina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-eo59erqx\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ghina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b4pe3d_p-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ghina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-eo59erqx\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ghina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b4pe3d_p-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ghina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eo59erqx\MySQL-python\
```

I'm on windows 10 using python 3.5 and django 1.9 , and I want to connect django to mysql database . When I run django server I get : No module named 'MySQLbd'

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL-Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) does not support Python 3.x. According to the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) you can use one of the following drivers:

> The Python Database API is described in PEP 249. MySQL has three prominent drivers that implement this API:
>
> [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) is a native driver that has been developed and supported for
>   over a decade by Andy Dustman.
>
> [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) is a fork of MySQLdb which
>   notably supports Python 3 and can be used as a drop-in replacement for
>   MySQLdb. At the time of this writing, this is the recommended choice
>   for using MySQL with Django.
>
> [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python) is a pure Python
>   driver from Oracle that does not require the MySQL client library or
>   any Python modules outside the standard library.